# push log file in promtail to loki

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, promtail

I have a promtail service running on a server sending .json formatted files to Loki/Grafana.  The json files are updated every few mins, but in a way that it appears Loki is not acknowledging the changes and loading them.  The files themselves are very small, so is there some way I can "force" them into Grafana, whether Promtail/Loki detect a change or not??  Thanks in advance for any guidance!